# Erro de sintaxis al actualizar datos

Tags: java, mysql, sql

soy nuevo en este grupo, en estos días he estado tratando de actualizar un registro pero me imprime el siguiente resultado

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '6' WHERE `Clave` =6' at line 1

[image: Este es el fragmento de código que utilizo para actualizar datos, en otras clases donde lo utilizo me funciona, pero en esta clase no]

[image: Esta es la estructura de mi BD]

[image: Y esta es la llamada al método de Actualizar]

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y en la medida de lo posible cambiar imágenes por el código en texto, de esta manera será más sencillo obtener respuestas**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es confundir dónde van ubicadas las comillas simples. Estas deben envolver el valor a insertar.

Debería quedarse como sigue (lo puedes completar tu mismo):

```
String Select = "UPDATE Materia SET "
+ "Clave = '" + regm.getCveMat() + "'"
+ ", Nombre = '" + regm.getNombre() + "'"
...
+ " WHERE Clave = '" + rerm.getCveMat() + "'";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Roger, efectivamente era un error de comillas